# What is the right way to build an angularjs app with ligthweight NPM dependencies?

Tags: angularjs, npm, gulp

I am developing an angularjs app. I am using npm to download JS dependencies.
Thus all my dependencies are located in `node_modules` folder of my app. This is working fine.

I would like now to deliver my app but the `node_modules` folder is huge ~30M and there a lot of heavy files that I didn't care.
My app is just including the minified version of the js files such as `node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js` for instance.

So, I wonder how to proceed to build my app with only the used minified js files to get a lightweight build?

In my case, I just care about the minified version of the js files.
I don't know if that possible or in which direction shall I dig?

I am already using gulp in my project to automate tasks, this would be great if there is a 'gulp' way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could run two new gulp task
the first will copy all your node js files to a target destination.
the second will concatenate and minify the js files into a single file.

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');  
var rename = require('gulp-rename');  
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify'); 

var dest = 'destination/';
var concatSource = dest;
var concatDest = 'dist/scripts/'

gulp.task('copy-minified', [], function() {

    var paths = [
        [
            'node_modules/**/*.js'
        ]
    ];

    paths.forEach(function(path) {

        gulp.src(path)
            .pipe(
                gulp.dest(dest)
            );

    });

});

gulp.task('concatenate-into-on-file-and-minify', function() {  
    return gulp.src(concatSource)
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(concatDest))
        .pipe(rename('scripts.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(concatDest));
});
```

Comment: ok, thanks for the tip, but this won't work in all case because some of my NODE modules such as [this one](https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select) doe not come with a minified js file.

Comment: @ben.IT I modified my answer. Now I copy the non minified js files concatenate them and then minify them. 
Regards,

Comment: if we do that, this gonna take all the .js files such as gruntfile.js and this is not what is expected. But inspired by your clue, I list in an array at the beginning of my gulpfile, the dependencies of my app that are concatenated in one file by a gulp task that concatenate and uglify.